# The problem of using regular expressions in the shell script

Tags: regex, powershell, shell

I have a regex that removes the content in the Activity tag.  The regex is `\s*<activity .*>(?:\s|\S)*<\/activity>`. It is possible in Java, but it will not work when written in the shell. The wording in the shell is as follows:

```sh
sed 's+\s*<activity .*>(?:\s|\S)*<\/activity>++g' AndroidManifest.xml
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.unity3d.player" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <application>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density" android:hardwareAccelerated="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
      <meta-data android:name="android.notch_support" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-mode" android:value="0" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-enable" android:value="True" />
    <meta-data android:name="notch.config" android:value="portrait|landscape" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.build-id" android:value="07a923ed-bdbd-46ed-98bd-afef17a7904a" />
  </application>
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.vulkan.version" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

What should I do. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean `\s+\s*<activity .*>(?:\s|\S)*<\/activity>`?

Comment: @Vishnudev I don’t understand too much. I just put this regular expression in Java and it works, but it doesn’t work when it’s put in a shell script.

Comment: @Vishnudev this  \s*<activity .*>(?:\s|\S)*<\/activity>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of regular expression are roughly classified in three
variants: BRE, ERE and PCRE. The latter has more features and power of
expression. Your regex is written in PCRE while `sed` supports up to ERE.
Another problem is that `sed` processes the input file line by line and
it requires some trick to make `sed` regex match across lines.

With `sed` please try the following:

```
sed -E '
:l              # define a label "l"
N               # append the next line of input into the pattern space
$!b l           # repeat until the last line
                # then whole lines are stored in the pattern space
s+[[:blank:]]*<activity .*>.*<\/activity>++g
                # perform the replace command over the pattern space
' AndroidManifest.xml
```

- The `-E` option enables ERE
- It slurps the whole file at first then performs the replacement next.

BTW if `perl` is your option, you can apply your regex `as is`:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's+\s*<activity .*>(?:\s|\S)*<\/activity>++g' AndroidManifest.xml
```

There is one caveat regarding the `(?:\s|\S)*` expression. The quantifier `*`
is greedy and tries to match as long as possible. If the xml file contains multiple `<activity> .. </activity>`
tags, the entire block across the tags is removed including the intermediate lines which should
not be removed. It will be better to rewrite it as: `(?:\s|\S)*?` or
`[\s\S]*?` in a common manner.